# Why is this CNN-script not predicting correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am quite new to both Python and Machine Learning and I am working on my first real project for image recognition. It is based upon [this tutorial](https://becominghuman.ai/building-an-image-classifier-using-deep-learning-in-python-totally-from-a-beginners-perspective-be8dbaf22dd8) which only has two classifications (cat or dog) and has a LOT more data. Nonetheless, I am not getting my multi-class script to work in terms of it predicting correctly but mainly how to troubleshoot the script. The script is nowhere near in predicting correctly.

[image: Examples of domino images in the training data]

Below is the script. The data/images consist of 7 folders with about 10-15 images each. The images are 100x100px of different domino tiles and one folder are just baby photos (mainly as a control group because they are very different to the domino photos):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import model_from_json
import numpy
import os

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (25, 25), input_shape = (100, 100, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (25, 25), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 7, activation = 'sigmoid')) # 7 units equals amount of output categories

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
    target_size = (100, 100),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'categorical')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
    target_size = (100, 100),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'categorical')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
    steps_per_epoch = 168,
    epochs = 35,
    validation_data = test_set,
    validation_steps = 3)
classifier.summary()

# serialize weights to HDF5
classifier.save_weights("dominoweights.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

path = 'dataset/prediction_images/' # Folder with my images
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  if "jpg" in filename:
    test_image = image.load_img(path + filename, target_size = (100, 100))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = classifier.predict(test_image)
    print result
    training_set.class_indices
    folder = training_set.class_indices.keys()[(result[0].argmax())] # Get the index of the highest predicted value
    if folder == '1':
      prediction = '1x3'
    elif folder == '2':
      prediction = '1x8'
    elif folder == '3':
      prediction = 'Baby'
    elif folder == '4':
      prediction = '5x7'
    elif folder == '5':
      prediction = 'Upside down'
    elif folder == '6':
      prediction = '2x3'   
    elif folder == '7':
      prediction = '0x0'
    else:
      prediction = 'Unknown'
    print "Prediction: " + filename + " seems to be " + prediction
  else:
    print "DSSTORE"
  print "\n"
```

**Explanations:**

- Training data: about 10-15 images each in each category. In total there are 168 training images
- Test data: 3 images each in each category
- `dataset/prediction_images/` contains about 10 different images that the script will predict
- `result` typically outputs `array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)`

**My question(s)**

My main question is: Do you see anything particularly wrong with the script? Or, should the script be working fine and that it's just the lack of data that makes the prediction wrong?

Subquestions:

1. Am I understanding the convolution layer(s) correctly that there is a 25x25px window that scans the images. I tried the "default" 3x3px but with the same result?
2. The number 32 in the convolution layer. Does it refer to 32 bit images?
3. Is it normal to have 2 convolution layers? I can't really see why it is needed.
4. The entire section with:

   `classifier.fit_generator(training_set,`
       `steps_per_epoch = 168,`
       `epochs = 35,`
       `validation_data = test_set,`
       `validation_steps = 3)`

puzzles me. As far as I understood, `steps_per_epoch` should be the number of training images I have. Is that correct? Are `epochs` the amount of iterations the CNN does?

5. I don't see why this code is needed:

   `from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`
   `train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,`
   `shear_range = 0.2,`
   `zoom_range = 0.2,`
   `horizontal_flip = True)`
   `test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)`

it seems to me that it is creating copies/versions of the images, zoom in on them, flips them etc. Why would this be needed?

Any tips on this would help me immensely!

Comment: IMHO you won't get anything good with this particular problem with this little data and without any special logic. If you'd use multiple orders of magnitude (thousand or million) more training data, then a bruteforce option might work, but if you have 10 examples per category then you need a lot of extra data (e.g. layers that are pretrained on imagenet) - simply think about the degrees of freedom; you have 10000 input parameters, 20000+ independent trainable parameters in your neural network, and you want to set those 20000 parameters from 168 training values - that's the way to overfitting.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I tried this in Octave on a normal Neural Network and got it working with the same amount of data (although, only 3 classes) so I thought I could solve it with Python/Keras as well. I chose dominoes as I thought it would be very easy to distinguish (it's basically just white blocks with black dots). Is there a better way to solve this than a CNN then? Getting 1000's of images will not be possible.

Comment: There are a bunch of standard approaches for situations like this: one is transfer learning; use the "lower layers" learned from a structurally similar problem where sufficient data is available (i.e. pretrained ImageNet models); and the second is data augmentation - generate many training examples from each real one with transformations to which your model should be invariant - e.g. rotation, translation and noise; and the third option - more data. Annotating a thousand images from google takes just an hour or two, in your case maybe artificially generated 3d images would also be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't seem to have anything clearly wrong, but filters of size `(25,25)` may be somewhat not good.

There are two possibilities:

- Train metrics are great, but test metrics are bad: your model is overfitting (it may be due to little data)
- Train metrics are not good: your model is not good enough

**Subquestions:**

1 - Yes, you're using filters that are windows sized (25,25) that slide along the input images. The bigger your filters, the less general they can be.

2 - The number 32 refers to how many output "channels" you want for this layer. While your input images have 3 channels, red layer, green layer and blue layer, these convolution layers will produce 32 different channels. The meaning of each channel is up to the hidden mathematics we can't see.

- The number of channels is totally independent from anything.
- The only restrictions are: input channels are 3, output classes are 7.

3 - It's normal to have "a lot" of convolutional layers, one over another. Some well known models have more than 10 convolutional layers.

- Why is it needed? Each convolutional layer is interpreting the results of the previous layer, and producing new results. It's more power to the model. One may be too few.

4 - Generators produce batches with shape `(batch_size,image_side1, image_side2, channels)`.

- `steps_per_epoch` is necessary because the generators used are infinite (so keras doesn't know when to stop)
- Usually, one uses `steps_per_epoch = total_images//batch_size`, so one epoch will use exactly all images. But you can play with these numbers as you wish
- Usually, one epoch is one iteration through the entire dataset. (But with generators and `steps_per_epoch`, that is up to the user)

5 - The image data generator, besides loading data from your folders and making the classes for you, is also a tool for **data augmentation**.

- If you have too little data, your model will overfit (excellent train results, terrible test results).
- Machine learning needs tons of data to work well
- Data augmentation is a way of creating more data when you don't have enough

  - A shifted, flipped, elongated, etc. image, in the vision of a model, is totally new
  - A model can learn cats looking to the right and yet not learn cats looking to the left, for instance

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe the best way of trying if the script has to do with too few examples is to download "cats, dogs, bird" etc images en masse and see if it behaves the same way. I do have a few follow up questions though:

Comment: 1. Regarding the window in the convolution layer. So, I assume I can just keep the filter at 32 then and don't worry much more about it? In my case of the domino tiles, they are just white tiles with different amounts of black dots. I thought a window that is too small would just look at each dot as a characteristic and it would be completely confused? It would make sense in terms of cats and dogs where one feature could be "paw" or "ear" but for a specific domino tile, it has to look at the entire domino tile (which sometimes could take up 1/2 of the image). Would 3x3 still be better?

Comment: 2. Regarding the generator. So, if my total amount of images are 168 should my steps_per_epoch be 168 and nbr of epochs be 1? Will further amount of epochs better my prediction?

Comment: `steps_per_epoch = total_images//batch_size`. Epochs is up to you. Choose enough for your loss to become stable.

Comment: But since 168 is not a multiple of 32, you may consider using different batch sizes, such as `batch_size=21` and `steps_per_epoch=8`.

Comment: The number of filters is related to the capability of your model. We can't know the correct number, but it does have an influence. Testing, testing, testing, that's how people choose the most suited models.

Comment: The size of the filters is also something you may experiment with. The best models known are made of many conv layers 3x3.

Comment: Ah, I see. I still don't understand everything but this has answered my main concerns. Thank you!!