# How do I handle input/output files running a script on Amazon EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a fairly default Python-script (as [can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156010/why-is-this-cnn-script-not-predicting-correctly)) in Machine Learning used for image recognition for cats and dogs. As I have a Macbook Pro (without an Nvidia GPU) I believe my best be is to run it on EC2.

What I can't wrap my head around though are how to handle my input and output files. I have uploaded the 8000 images to S3. I could copy and paste my script into the console of EC2 I guess but I would prefer to run it from a file. In the script it also creates/saves a .h5 file with the trained model that I want to save and download to my computer.

How do I solve this in practise? Can I upload and run my script from S3? Can I get my .h5-file saved to my folder on S3 as well? How do I do this, in that case?

Comment: Are you familiar with SSH and `scp`…?

Comment: [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) could also be your friend here in addition to scp

Comment: Not at all, but maybe I can learn. My question is more generic than that though. What I mean is mainly where do I put the files? Do I put them on S3? Do I upload them to my temporary instance on EC2 (which won't be applicable for data). Do I run the script with reference to S3 in the .flow_from_directory?